# Key mapping I don't understand

Tags: key-bindings

I'm learning key mappings, I know that:

```
:imap <c-d> <esc>ddi
```

means "If you are in 'insert' mode and press `ctrl+d`, it performs first `<esc>` like you have been pressed the <kbd>esc</kbd> key and then press `d`, `d` and `i`". So you escape from insert mode, delete a line and enter insert mode again.

Ok, but I find this:

```
:map <F2> a<C-R>=strftime("%c")<CR><Esc>
```

And I don't understand, if I read it like the fisrt command I get "If I press `F2` it's like press the key `a` with `ctrl+shift+r`(uppercase R)? and then it prints the `strftime` and `<CR>`?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take it bit by bit:

```
map <F2> a<C-R>=strftime("%c")<CR><Esc>

map                                     Create a mapping in several modes (Normal, Visual, Select, Operator-pending)
    <F2>                                Map the key F2
         a                              Start insert mode with `a` i.e. after the cursor position
          <C-r>                         Insert the content of a register see `:h i_CTRL-R` (http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R)
               =                        Here we will use the expression register see `:h i_CTRL-R_=` (http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_%3d)
                                        That means that we will enter an expression, it will get evaluated and the result will be inserted
                strftime("%c")          This is the expression to be executed see `:h strftime()` (http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#strftime%28%29)
                                        with %c as a parameter this returns something like: Sun Apr 27 11:49:23 1997
                              <CR>      To validate the expression we used in the expression register
                                  <Esc> And escape to normal mode once we are done
```

So indeed this mapping switches to insert mode, inserts the current date and time and switches back to normal mode

A few observations about this command:

- Never use `map` instead use mode specific commands, and unless you know what you are doing always use the non recursive version of these commands, here you most probably want `nnoremap` (since the commands switches to insert mode with `a`)
- Key notations ([`:h key-notation`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation)) like `<C-r>`, `<CR>`, `<F2>` are case insensitive.
- You can experiment with the expression register by yourself: in insert mode just press <kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> and experiment with different expressions.

Comment: @BLayer Good point I never use `map` without a mode so I always forget which mode it actually creates a mapping in. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: NP. I hear you...I never use bare `map` either.

Comment: In this particular case, that could also be written `"=strftime(…)<cr>p` i think